# How do you set a variable in Racket after evaluating a condition

Tags: variables, binding, scheme, racket

I'm having trouble setting variables in Racket following evaluation of a condition. If I have a function definition like

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x y z)
    (cond
      ((> 3 2)
        (what code here?)))))
```

Say I want to set the variable z to the value 10 if the condition evaluates to true, what is the syntax?

Comment: Normally, you avoid modifying variables' values in Racket (and Scheme). It's better  to ask about the problem that you want to solve by doing this than about this particular solution you have in mind.

Comment: Because Racket has lexical scoping , the scope of `z` is internal to `foo`. So there's no way to access `z` after `foo` has run, the name and the value are gone. There's actually more to the story since the compiler will  mangle `z` to a unique symbol in order to avoid a certain class of bugs that arise with global variable names.

Comment: @benrudgers That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In Scheme we set variables like this:

```
(set! z 10)
```

... But it's frowned upon, normally you want to avoid mutating state at all costs. Remember, Scheme at its core is a functional programming language; there must be a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish without changing the value of a variable. Most likely, you'll want to call the recursion with the new value for the `z` parameter:

```
(foo x y 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have said, it is bad practice to use this imperative style of programming within racket. That being said, however, doesn't mean it can't be done! A first attempt doing it as a function might look like:

```
(define (setter variable condition value)
  (if condition (begin (set! variable value) variable) variable))
(define a 10)
(setter a #t 5)
a
```

Running this returns 5 and 10. This is where we begin to see the lexical scope of a function. Variables are always defined in their scope, a nice system that lets us do things like use 'list' as the name of a function parameter despite list being a function in racket. Racket will just assume you mean the variable defined in the current scope, and override previous variables.

Basically, we want the `(set! variable value)` call to happen within the scope we care about, namely outside of the setter function. Note that:
`a (set! a 10) a` returns 10 5, meaning it does what we want. Hmm, now if only we could make setter actually become the code `(set! variable value)` if we passed it a true condition. That would put it in the desired scope.

And we can! This is where Racket's Macro system comes into play. In Racket (and scheme and lisp languages), the programs you write are data just like numbers and booleans, which means you can manipulate them and return new values.

```
(define-syntax-rule (setter variable condition value)
  (if condition (begin (set! variable value) variable) variable))
```

Now, setter does what we want it to.

```
(define a 10)
a
(setter a #t 5)
a
```

properly returns 10 5 5. In short, macros are awesome. See the racket guide for some great tutorials on how to use them and what they can do.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. I'm not planning on doing a lot of work in Racket (or Scheme) but Macros sounds like exactly what I need to look at.